# Cannot update. Database or object is read-only. Error

Tags: sql, database

I'm getting the following response when trying to enter a record in a database. I recently updated my server from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.

"Cannot update. Database or object is read-only."

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a bit more details ? What is giving you the error ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probobly permissions check what account IIS is running under, grant acess to IIS_IUSR/networkservice.

And provide more info about your problem.